# How can I disable a plugin programmatically

Tags: c++, plugins, browser, registry, firebreath

I have created a npapi plugin. Now in order to enable or disable it, I invoke regsvr32 command from my program. Now, I wish to selectively disable the plugin, e.g plugin should be disabled for firefox but enabled for chrome. Perhaps, it could be done by altering some keys, but I don't know exactly which ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enable it for just one browser unless you install it as part of an extension instead of in the registry.